Data structure : can we create an environment that we can use in only one other environment?
I want to create an environment that is allowed in only one other environment.
For a command, we have \let\command\environment@command but the command \let don't work with this exemple :
\let\begin{env}\begin{environment@env}
Anyone know anything about that ?

Welcome to TeX.SX! \let\env\environment@env and \let\endenv\endenvironment@env should work. But I'm not sure it is the better way to do that. Maybe \NewEnvironmentCopy{env}{environment@env} is better. Anyway, the reason of creating such environment isn't very clear for me (do you want to raise an error if the environment is used outside the dedicated one ? Maybe a flag would be simpler).

You can define the inner environment within the definition of the outer environment if you want it to be only known within that environment. However, it's not clear from your command/environment analogy what you're trying to achieve; it seems irrelevant to the stated question.

does it need to be undefined outside or just do nothing or give an error? if it just needs to do nothing, another option is to use a boolean which is true only within the outer environment. then your inner environment tests this and does nothing in case it is false. or it could issue a warning, raise an error etc.

\let\begin... tries to redefine the \begin macro.

Instead of only defining your environment inside the other I'd suggest to define it globally and let it test whether it's been used nested in the outer environment, and otherwise let it throw a meaningful error. Something like the following:
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifinmyouter
\newenvironment{myouter}{\inmyoutertrue}{}
\newenvironment{myinner}
  {%
    \ifinmyouter
    \else
      \GenericError{}
        {Incorrect use of myinner environment}
        {You should use myinner only nested in myouter}{}%
    \fi
  }{}
\begin{document}
\begin{myouter}
  \begin{myinner}
  \end{myinner}
\end{myouter}

\begin{myinner}% throws error
\end{myinner}
\end{document}


If you want to copy over some internal definition of your environment, I'd suggest using \NewEnvironmentCopy/\RenewEnvironmentCopy/\DeclareEnvironmentCopy provided by the LaTeX kernel instead of manually defining something which most likely has flaws (copying document level commands in LaTeX is not as straight forward as \let because of different optional argument grabbing systems, something the kernel version takes care of, mostly).
Still I'd define a version of the environment throwing a meaningful error message for use outside of the outer environment:
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{myinner@private}{Stuff}{done}
\newenvironment{myinner}
  {%
    \GenericError{}
      {Incorrect use of myinner environment}
      {You should use myinner only nested in myouter}{}%
  }
  {}

\newenvironment{myouter}{\DeclareEnvironmentCopy{myinner}{myinner@private}}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{myouter}
  \begin{myinner}
  \end{myinner}
\end{myouter}

\begin{myinner}
\end{myinner}
\end{document}

